# Решение кубического уравнения с++

Tags: c++

D = x^3 − 3x^2 − 12x + 10, где x — глубина кладки в метрах, а D — уровень опасности в условных единицах. Для тестирования гипотезы нужно взять пробу грунта на безопасной, согласно формуле, глубине.

Напишите программу, находящую такое значение глубины х, при котором уровень опасности наиболее близок к нулю, учитывая допустимое отклонение. На вход программе подаётся максимально допустимое отклонение уровня опасности от нуля, а программа должна рассчитать приблизительное значение х, удовлетворяющее этому отклонению. Известно, что глубина точно больше нуля и меньше четырёх метров.

Введите максимально допустимый уровень опасности: 0,01

Вывод:

Приблизительная глубина безопасной кладки: 0,732422 метра

Пробовал описать некоторые математические способы, н приводит к комплексным числам

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну, вообще-то формулы Кардано обычно и в самом деле дают комплексные числа. Сопряженные. Так что конечный ответ — по крайней мере один — получается действительным :) Но ведь можно применить и численные методы... Ваше уравнение имеет корни 5 и 1±√3, если интересует, так что решение, лежащее в диапазоне, только одно — 1+√3. Метод деления отрезка [0,4] пополам отлично его найдет...

Comment: @Harry где-то минус потеряли `-1 ± √3` : `-1 + √3 == 0.732` Кстати, пополам такие уравнения не решаются. Прогу как-то нарисовал методом Ньютона в комплексном поле. Решает классно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ну, комментарий не ответ, уже не отредактировать...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что от вас хотят численного решения уравнения с заданной точностью. Что-то вроде этого:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double D(double x) {
    return ((x - 3) * x - 12) * x + 10;
    }

int main() {
    double a = 0, b = 4, fa = D(a), fb = D(b);

    if (fa * fb > 0) {
        cout << "Maybe no solution\n";
        return 0;
        }

    while (b - a > 0.0001) {
        double c = (a + b) / 2;
        double fc = D(c);

        if (fc * fa < 0)
            b = c;
        else
            a = c;
        }

    cout << a << '\n';
    }
```